# nested if/else statements talked about assigning variables...I've already done that and it still doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, nested

Why won't my nested if/else statements work: it takes me to bing.com as a search engine no matter what adult age I enter; everything else works correctly.

```
function adult_jump(SelectSE, SelectWD, age) {
if (SelectSE==true) {
if (age <= 45) {
window.location = "http://www.google.com"
} else {
window.location = "http://www.bing.com"
} 
} else {
if (SelectWD==true) {
  window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com"
} else {
  window.alert("You must select a search tool!")
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while comparing with true or false.. it is better to use the === operator..  i modified the window.location to alert..  [so you can see all results at once here](http://jsfiddle.net/5e89G/)

```
function adult_jump(SelectSE, SelectWD, age) { 

  if (SelectSE === true) {
   if (age <= 45) {
   alert("http://www.google.com") ;  }  
   else { alert("http://www.bing.com") ; } 
} 

else {
  if (SelectWD === true) {
  alert("http://www.yahoo.com") ; } 
  else { alert("You must select a search tool!") ;}  
} 

}

adult_jump(true,false,30); // alerts google
adult_jump(true,false,48); // alerts bing
adult_jump(false,true,0) ; //alerts yahoo
adult_jump("","",0) ; // alerts select a search tool
```